# Does ReactiveDiscoveryClient.probe actually do anything?

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, project-reactor

I'm looking through the code for ReactiveDiscoveryClient and I noticed the following

```java
    Flux<String> getServices();

    /**
     * Can be used to verify the client is still valid and able to make calls.
     * <p>
     * A successful invocation with no exception thrown implies the client is able to make
     * calls.
     * <p>
     * The default implementation simply calls {@link #getServices()} - client
     * implementations can override with a lighter weight operation if they choose to.
     */
    default void probe() {
        getServices();
    }
```

But since `getServices()` returns a `Flux` and `Flux` don't do anything until `subscribe` occurs, would `probes` using the default implementation be a no-op?

Comment: I would say not except that which is done during the implementing classes construction.

Comment: The thing is there is no return value for probe aside from a throw.  So unless creating the flux itself throws the exception there's nothing really to indicate any error.

Comment: Not exactly. You point to an interface. When `probe` is called there must be some class that has implemented the interface. When the class is instantiated its constructor is called. Things would have been done there but it would have been done anyway. Calling probe will not do anything but the implementation classes constructor will have done something for what that's worth. See, e.g., `ReactiveCompositeDiscoveryClient`. The method `getServices` could conceivably do something before constructing the `Flux` but who knows.

Comment: See the consul implementation